# Excel - Formula to read a row and return true if two criteria is met

Tags: excel, formula

I am looking for a formula to read an entire row (2:2, 3:3 etc) and identify if a value of >= 80% AND <= 20% are within this row. If this is the case, return true. I have tried a lot of different formula but could not identify one that works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 80% and 20% of what? A sum of values will always contain it's 20% and 80% (adding up to 100% in fact...)

Comment: In general it would be good to provide a proper example of expected input and output and also please show us these "different formulas" you tried *(or at least one you expect to be closest to correct)*

Comment: #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! 0 #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! 0.91 0.17 0

Here's an example of a row, which contains both values I am looking for. There are 1000s of rows like this. Note the DIV/0 means there was no value for this. That's fine. I'm looking for those that have >= 0.8 AND <= 0.2. 

The closest I thought would work is similar to the one Olly suggested, the AND function. I did not use COUNTIFs before though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(2:2,">="&0.8),COUNTIF(2:2,"<="&0.2))
```

**EDIT:**

This should work, ignoring the #DIV/0! errors:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS(2:2,">0",2:2,">=0.8"),COUNTIFS(2:2,">0",2:2,"<=0.2"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.
#DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! 0 #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! #DIV/0! 0.91 0.17 0 

Here's an example of a row, which contains both values I am looking for. There are 1000s of rows like this. Note the DIV/0 means there was no value for this which is no problem in this scenario.

Comment: Edited formula in my answer, to account for the #DIV/0! errors

Comment: They all return as a 0 for every row

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.